# Free database of vehicle data and VIN

Tags: data-request, transportation

I've been looking for a free database of vehicle manufacturer's specifications, data, and VIN for a long time with no luck, does anyone have any ideas?

**Please identify any database of free or non-free, you know. Free database are more important.**

Information required from the following manufacturers:

- Acura
- Alfa Romeo
- Audi
- Baic
- Bentley
- Benz
- Besturn
- BMW
- Brilliance
- BYD
- Chervrolet
- Chery
- Citroen
- Daewoo
- Daf
- Dodge
- Ferrari
- Fiat
- Ford
- Geely
- GMC
- Great Wall
- Haima
- Honda
- Hummer
- Hyundai
- Infiniti
- Jaguar
- Jepp
- Kia
- Lada
- Landrover
- Lexus
- Lifan
- Lotus
- Maserati
- Mazda
- MG
- Mini
- Mitsubishi
- Nissan
- Opel
- Peugeot
- Porsche
- Renault
- Rover
- Smart
- Ssang Young
- Subaru
- Suzuki
- Tesla
- Toyota
- Volkswagen
- Volvo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this information tending to differ by region/continent. Maybe you should check which could fitting best to you and/or merge them.

- Here you can request an API Key: https://vindecoder.eu/ It is not free.
- From [NHTSA](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/) you can get lots of different car/manufactur information as WMI.
- http://www.vinquery.com/ provides good api support.
- [edmunds.com](http://developer.edmunds.com/api-documentation/vehicle/spec_vin_decoding/v2/) <del>has</del> had<sup>*</sup> a well documented API.
- [DataOne Software](http://www.dataonesoftware.com/web-services-vin-decoder-api) has a non free API

<sup>* As of Feb 2018, they have closed their openAPI program</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From Vehicle Databases, you can get different APIs like VIN Decoder API, Window Sticker API, Car Market Value API, Car Photos API and more. You can get it from here https://vehicledatabases.com/ but they are not free.